# Automatically get loop index in foreach loop in Perl

Tags: perl, foreach

If I have the following array in Perl:

```
@x = qw(a b c);
```

and I iterate over it with `foreach`, then `$_` will refer to the current *element* in the array:

```
foreach (@x) {
    print;
}
```

will print:

```
abc
```

Is there a similar way to get the *index* of the current element, without manually updating a counter? Something such as:

```
foreach (@x) {
    print $index;
}
```

where `$index` is updated like `$_` to yield the output:

```
012
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Like [codehead said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974656/automatically-get-loop-index-in-foreach-loop-in-perl/974679#974679), you'd have to iterate over the array indices instead of its elements. I prefer this variant over the C-style `for` loop:

```perl
for my $i (0 .. $#x) {
    print "$i: $x[$i]\n";
}
```

Comment: This is not what you want if array index sequence is 2, 5, 8, 19 with gaps in sequence. I believe the question was something regarding index of current element.

Comment: The only way to generalize for an array with gaps is to put the line, `next unless defined $x[$i];` at the start of the loop.  This seems to be true also for all the more risky solutions involving while/each and for/keys.  Apparently the array iterator sees each sequential index whether it exists or not.

Comment: I just thought of a better way to write that line: `$x[$i] // next;`

Comment: $# syntax is not supported perl 5.30..

Comment: `$#` is a long deprecated, and now removed, special variable, but `$#arrayname` is not the same same thing and continues to work.
https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5300delta
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Deprecated-and-removed-variables

Answer (score 48):

In Perl prior to 5.10, you can say

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw/a b c d e/;

my $index;
for my $elem (@a) {
    print "At index ", $index++, ", I saw $elem\n";
}

#or

for my $index (0 .. $#a) {
    print "At index $index I saw $a[$index]\n";
}
```

In Perl 5.10, you use [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) to declare a variable that never gets reinitialized (unlike ones created with [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html)). This lets you keep the `$index` variable in a smaller scope, but it can lead to bugs (if you enter the loop a second time it will still have the last value):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw/a b c d e/;

for my $elem (@a) {
    state $index;
    say "At index ", $index++, ", I saw $elem";
}
```

In Perl 5.12 you can say

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012; # This enables strict
use warnings;

my @a = qw/a b c d e/;

while (my ($index, $elem) = each @a) {
    say "At index $index I saw $elem";
}
```

But be warned: you there are [restrictions](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) to what you are allowed to do with `@a` while iterating over it with `each`.

It won't help you now, but in Perl 6 you will be able to say

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6

my @a = <a b c d e>;
for @a Z 0 .. Inf -> $elem, $index {
    say "at index $index, I saw $elem"
}
```

The `Z` operator zips the two lists together (i.e. it takes one element from the first list, then one element from the second, then one element from the first, and so on).  The second list is a [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) list that contains every integer from 0 to infinity (at least theoretically).  The `-> $elem, $index` says that we are taking two values at a time from the result of the zip.  The rest should look normal to you (unless you are not familiar with the [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) function from 5.10 yet).

Comment: I don't like the section on `state`, I think it would be better served with `{ my $index; ... }`.

Comment: I liked this solution: `while (my ($i, $elem) = each @a)`

Answer (score 21):

`perldoc perlvar` does not seem to suggest any such variable.

Comment: [*AndrewKS*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444794/andrewks): This certainly is *not* against the spirit of StackOverflow. If you had tried `perldoc perlvar`, you would know why. Only variables listed in `perldoc perlvar` exist. Such a variable, as I already stated, does not exist.

Comment: This *is* against the spirit of stackoverflow, because the spirit is to provide an answer that can answer a question in it's entirety, without external resources. Providing optional resources such as links or terminal commands to run for learning is a bonus, but not the *spirit*. The fact that you had to provide further information in a comment is proof that this answer is not enough on it's own.

Comment: This is basically the same as a link-only answer.

Comment: Perhaps expand your answer?

Answer (score 12):

It can be done with a `while` loop (`foreach` doesn't support this):

```
my @arr = (1111, 2222, 3333);

while (my ($index, $element) = each(@arr))
{
   # You may need to "use feature 'say';"
   say "Index: $index, Element: $element";
}
```

Output:

```
Index: 0, Element: 1111
Index: 1, Element: 2222
Index: 2, Element: 3333
```

Perl version: 5.14.4

Comment: Perldoc says not to use While-Each --- It's easy enough to explicitly reset the iterator before starting a loop, but there is no way to insulate the iterator state used by a loop from the iterator state used by anything else that might execute during the loop body. To avoid these problems, use a foreach loop rather than while-each.--- https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html

Answer (score 8):

Not with `foreach`.

If you definitely need the element cardinality in the array, use a 'for' iterator:

```
for ($i=0; $i<@x; ++$i) {
  print "Element at index $i is " , $x[$i] , "\n";
}
```

Comment: foreach and for are interchangeable synonyms.  Some introductory material tries to use for to mean the C-style loop and foreach for the list iterator loop, but that use of terminology isn't going to be familiar to everyone.

Comment: foreach and for are /not/ interchangeable, as this instance shows.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen It is more correct to say that you can replace the keyword foreach with the keyword for, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: Quoting from 'perldoc perlvar': The "foreach" keyword is actually a synonym for the "for" keyword, so you can use "foreach" for readability or "for" for brevity. endquote. So they *are* interchangeable. Try it.

Comment: The keywords are interchangeable -- but the loops themselves have different meanings. A "for" loop is a loop with an incrementing (or decrementing) variable, even if it's introduced with the foreach keyword. A "foreach" loop has an internal iterator, even if it's introduced with the for keyword. The OP wanted access to the iterator, so he wants a "for" loop, regardless of the keyword used.

Comment: a C-style for loop (that y'all keep calling a "for loop") doesn't have to increment/decrement a variable, e.g.: for (my $iter = new_iter(); $iter; $iter = $iter->next() ) { ... }

Answer (score 5):

No, you must make your own counter. Yet another example:

```
my $index;
foreach (@x) {
    print $index++;
}
```

when used for indexing

```
my $index;
foreach (@x) {
    print $x[$index]+$y[$index];
    $index++;
}
```

And of course you can use `local $index;` instead `my $index;` and so and so.

Comment: 0+ is unneedded; postincrement returns 0 if the variable incremented was undef.

Comment: @ysth: You can be surprised when someone somewhere in application use same global $index variable as you. But if you write short script and you assume ... no, don't do it.

Comment: This answer is arguably more readable than the `for` loop syntax of `for(my $index; $index <= $#x; $index++){}`.

Answer (score 4):

[`autobox::Core`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autobox::Core) provides, among many more things, a handy `for` method:

```
use autobox::Core;

['a'..'z']->for( sub{
    my ($index, $value) = @_;
    say "$index => $value";
});
```

Alternatively, have a look at an iterator module, for example: [`Array::Iterator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Array::Iterator)

```
use Array::Iterator;

my $iter = Array::Iterator->new( ['a'..'z'] );
while ($iter->hasNext) {
    $iter->getNext;
    say $iter->currentIndex . ' => ' . $iter->current;
}
```

Also see:

- [each to their own (autobox)](http://transfixedbutnotdead.com/2010/06/16/each-to-their-own-autobox/)
- [`perl5i`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5i)

Comment: I would replace the links to the distributions with a link of the form:
http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Array::Iterator

Comment: @Brad Gilbert:  Changed.  Though personally I prefer the top level (home) view presented by http://search.cpan.org/dist/Array-Iterator

Comment: I would agree that it is sometimes useful to point to the Dist view instead of the perldoc view. Also just because I *would* replace the links, doesn't necessarily mean that you *should*.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: This is a good example of TIMTOWTDI in perl perhaps? :)  Anyway its no problem and if the _perldoc_ link is becoming more prevalent on SO then I'm happy to switch to using it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I have checked so many books and other blogs... The conclusion is, there isn't any system variable for the loop counter. We have to make our own counter. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right, there is no accessible system counter. --- And "make our own counter" can be done many ways; the most common is probably the `for` (aka `foreach`) with the optional long syntax of `for($i=0;$i<=$#array;$i++){}`.

Answer (score 3):

Oh yes, you can! (sort of, but you shouldn't). `each(@array)` in a scalar context gives you the current index of the array.

```
@a = (a..z);
for (@a) { 
  print each(@a) . "\t" . $_ . "\n"; 
}
```

Here `each(@a)` is in a scalar context and returns only the index, not the value at that index. Since we're in a `for` loop, we have the value in $_ already. The same mechanism is often used in a while-each loop. Same problem.

The problem comes if you do `for(@a)` again. The index isn't back to 0 like you'd expect; it's `undef` followed by 0,1,2... one count off. The perldoc of `each()` says to avoid this issue. Use a `for` loop to track the index.

*[each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)*

Basically:

```
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#a; $i++) {
  print "The Element at $i is $a[$i]\n";
}
```

I'm a fan of the alternate method:

```
my $index=0;
for (@a) {
  print "The Element at $index is $a[$index]\n";
  $index++;
}
```

Comment: Nice try, but no.  each does not access the same iterator that the for loop is using.  The iterator of each is a part of the array or hash.  for creates its own list of aliases to the array and iterates over that.  You can see what I mean by using `each(@a)` again within the loop, for instance `print each(@a)."=< $_ >=".each(@a);`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is this way:

```
use List::Rubyish;

$list = List::Rubyish->new( [ qw<a b c> ] );
$list->each_index( sub { say "\$_=$_" } );
```

See [List::Rubyish](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Rubyish).

Answer (score 1):

Please consider:

```
print "Element at index $_ is $x[$_]\n" for keys @x;
```

Comment: I don't think that `keys @x` behaves as you think.  I'd expect it to return every even-indexed element.

Comment: `for keys @x` is in a list context, returns the current index, and to get the value you have to reference it `$x[$_]` --- A more readable way to write the exact same thing is `for my $idx (keys @x){print "Element at index $idx is $x[$idx]\n";}`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to know the index in most circumstances. You can do this:

```
my @arr = (1, 2, 3);
foreach (@arr) {
    $_++;
}
print join(", ", @arr);
```

In this case, the output would be **2, 3, 4** as foreach sets an alias to the actual element, not just a copy.

Comment: What would happen if you replace the first line with:

my @arr = ('foo', 'bar', 'foo');

Comment: It would print 1, 1, 1 since string scalars evaluate to zero when used in number context.

Comment: I know that I don't need the index in most circumstances.  The question is about the best way to get it when I do need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like....

```
@array = qw /tomato banana papaya potato/;             # Example array
my $count;                                             # Local variable initial value will be 0.
print "\nBefore For loop value of counter is $count";  # Just printing value before entering the loop.

for (@array) { print "\n",$count++," $_" ; }           # String and variable seperated by comma to
                                                       # execute the value and print.
undef $count;                                          # Undefining so that later parts again it will
                                                       # be reset to 0.

print "\nAfter for loop value of counter is $count";   # Checking the counter value after for loop.
```

In short...

```
@array = qw /a b c d/;
my $count;
for (@array) { print "\n",$count++," $_"; }
undef $count;
```

Comment: so you're basically suggesting that I keep track of the index manually.