# Iterate over first at most n elements of an perl array

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

What is the most pleasant idiomatic way of writing

```
for (take(100,@array)) {...}
```

given that there is no `take` (which takes the first *n* elements of a list, but fewer if there are not *n* elements)?

Things I considered:

- `for (@array[0..99]) {...}`

  but that fails ungraceful if `@array` has fewer than 100 elements
- `for (@array[0..min(99,$#array)]) {...}`

  but `min` is not a standard function in Perl
- `for (splice @array,0,100) {...}`

  bu that changes the array.

Comment: What does `take` do?

Comment: Would [iterating with an index variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/974656/132382) do what you want?

Comment: Not really; I’m looking for a way to get the elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *`for (@array[0..min(99,$#array)]) {...}`*
>   *but min is not a standard function in Perl*

[`min`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#min) is a standard function in the module [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html), which is part of core as of 5.7.3.

```
use List::Util qw(min);

for (@array[0..min(99,$#array)]) {  # generator in 5.8.8+
  ...
}
```

Note that perl 5.8.8 onward, and perhaps earlier, is smart enough to understand that expression as a generator rather than a slice.  That is, elements 0 through $terminus are fetched one at a time from @array instead of an anonymous slice being taken and copied.

Comment: Thanks; I was hoping for something more elegant, but I guess that’s the best solution available.

Comment: Do you know where it's documented (if anywhere) that this doesn't generate a temporary list? I know [the range operator by itself is optimized in `for` loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25214138/176646), although even the documentation for that is terse.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, no, I don't.  I used a `tie()`d array that barked about every FETCH to persuade myself that this optimization was in place.  (One successive FETCH per loop, rather than all at once.)

Comment: Nice approach! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6):

You want the CPAN module [`List::Slice`](http://metacpan.org/pod/List::Slice)

```
use List::Slice 'head';

foreach my $elem ( head 100, @things ) { ... }
```

Comment: `head` almost sounds like a basic "utility"  ...  for lists ;-)

Comment: Well, more "basic utility" than funky things like `gather/take`.

Comment: @G.Cito - yup. See https://github.com/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar-List-Utils/pull/23

Comment: Yes, I wish such a thing were easily expressible in the language itself, or at least be shipped by default.

Comment: The only downside is that in a `for` loop, this function will copy _n_ elements to an anonymous array that is then iterated over.  By contrast an explicit conventional slice in a `for` loop fetches elements one-by-one on each an iteration.  Doesn't matter unless _n_ gets big.

Answer (score 2):

You've indicated you've found the following the cleanest:

```
take(100, @array)
```

So to answer your question as to what's the cleanest, that is! I don't see why you're trying to find an alternative.

Comment: In other words, write a subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `map`:

```
my @array = qw ( 1 2 3 4 );
print join "\n", map { $_ // () } @array[0..10];
```

This takes 10 elements from a list, but applies the 'defined' test to it - and if it's not defined, returns an empty list.

So you could:

```
for ( map { $_ // () } @array[0..100] ) { 
   #do something
}
```

Note - `//` is a defined-or operator, only available from perl 5.10+. You could use instead a `defined` ternary:

```
print join "\n", map { defined ? $_ : () } @array[0..10];
```

Comment: Same problem as @simbabque’s solution: This breaks if not all elements are defined. Might be a corner case, but I don’t see a reason why the code should not be reliable.

Comment: I think [`boolean`](https://metacpan.org/release/boolean) would work here too :-D `perl -Mboolean -E '@array = ("a" .. "g", "", undef, undef, "x", "0", "z"); print join "\n", map { boolean($_) ? $_ : () } @array[0..100]; '`

Comment: Granted - it does filter `undef` as a result of what it's doing. I don't think that's much of a problem, because I very rarely have present-but-`undef` that I need to act on within a loop context.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional check inside of your loop to break once the end is reached.

```
my @arr = (1 .. 90);

for ( @arr[0..99]) {
    last unless defined $_;
    say;
}
```

But that would not work on arrays that have `undef` values in between, like these:

```
my @foo = (1, 2, undef, 4);
my @bar;
$bar[2] = 'foo'; # (undef, undef, 'foo')
```

Comment: Not just `undef`... anything that evaluates to false (`0`, `""`), etc.

Comment: @zaid Yes, of course. Feel free to edit, I'm on the phone.

Comment: “But that would not work on arrays that have undef values in between, like these” – that’d be a show-stopper for me, as it seems to be very unreliable then.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner If you don't want to add a lot of checks to your subroutine you could use a CPAN module for that part.  Would  [`boolean`](https://metacpan.org/release/boolean) be appropriate? See the end of my `gather/take` response for an example.

Answer (score 1):

The other responses have this covered but, just for thoroughness, there **are** a couple of "pumpkin perl" `gather/take` implementations on CPAN :-)

- [`List::Gather`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gather)
- [`Syntax::Keyword::Gather`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Gather)

There is also Damian Conway's [`Perl6::Gather`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Gather) which is pretty much the same but requires `Perl6::Export`.

They let you work with lists in the way you want. *e.g.* to "`take`" half the alphabet:

```
 perl -E 'use List::Gather; @lpha = ("a" .. "z"); 
         @half = gather { for (@lpha){ take $_ if gathered < 13 } } ; say @half'
 abcdefghijklm
```

or less if we aren't halfway there yet :

```
 perl -E 'use List::Gather; @lpha = ("a" .. "c");  
         @half = gather { for (@lpha) { take $_ if gathered < 13 } } ; say @half'
 abc
```

With [`List::Gather`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gather) the `gather` block can take a loop (because of lexical scoping inside `gather{}` ??) and the topic `$_` is required inside the block:

```
perl -E 'use List::Gather; @lpha = ("a" .. "g"); 
          @half = gather for (@lpha) { take $_ if gathered < 13 }; say @half'
```

With [`Syntax::Keyword::Gather`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Gather) you do that inside the `gather{}` block (which is also possible with `List::Gather`):

```
perl -E 'use Syntax::Keyword::Gather; @lpha = ("a".."g"); 
        @half = gather { for (@lpha){ take if gathered < 13 } }; say @half'
```

I find `gather/take` to be a nice alternative way to work with lists. Whether it is nice enough to ship with perl one day - say in `List::Util` - is an interesting implicit part of your question ;-) but they are on CPAN.

---

**Postscript**

To address some of the concerns about `defined`-ness  raised by @simbabque, @zaid and @Joachim Breitner more checks can be added to the `take()` routine.

Here I use Ingy's [`boolean`](https://metacpan.org/release/boolean):

```
perl -E 'use boolean; use List::Gather; 
        @lpha = ("a" .. "g", "", undef, undef, "x", "0", "z"); 
        @half = gather { for (@lpha){ take $_ if boolean($_) && gathered < 13 }};
        use DDP; p @half;'
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [0] "a",
    [1] "b",
    [2] "c",
    [3] "d",
    [4] "e",
    [5] "f",
    [6] "g",
    [7] "x",
    [8] "z"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use iterator pattern, i.e.

```
my $iterator = create_iterator(100);
while (my $element = $iterator->()) {
   ...;
}
```

There `limit` might be either embedded into iterator creation, i.e.

```
sub create_iterator {
     my $limit = shift;
     my @data = (0 x 1000);
     my $i = 0;
     return sub {
        return $data[$i++] if ($i < @data);
     }
}
```

PS. There is a limitation, that `undef` cannot be part of `@data`

Comment: This shares with the other answers the downside that is breaks if `undef` is in the list.